# installing ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on alienware x51 R3

Tags: alienware

I'm trying to do a full install of ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my Alienware x51 R3, but I keep getting [    3.016154]acpi pcc probe failed.

I tried changing boot mode to Legacy, but it still throws the same error.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it running fine in the Live USB/DVD mode?

Comment: No, it gives the same error. 
Mint installed just fine, but I'd rather use ubuntu if possible.